# How To Install Killsnoop on Ubuntu 20.04 server

Tags: command-line, apt

According to documentation: https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man8/killsnoop-bpfcc.8.html

I installed the bpfcc-tools

```
# apt-cache policy bpfcc-tools
bpfcc-tools:
  Installed: 0.12.0-2
  Candidate: 0.12.0-2
  Version table:
 *** 0.12.0-2 500
        500 http://cn.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

However this command still fails
`# killsnoop -h -x -p XXXX`

```
killsnoop: command not found
```

Am I missing a step?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct command seems to be

```
killsnoop-bpfcc
```

You can check it by

```
dpkg -L bpfcc-tools
```

I filed a bug report to Launchpad regarding the man page.